# Question regarding frequency of pendulum while it is stopping

Tags: frequency, wavelength

As a pendulum stops, the frequency increases, but of course the pendulum stops. So does the frequency increase so much that it... turns to 0? Or does this have to do with wavelength or speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our usual model for a pendulum, the frequency is constant down to zero amplitude.  The excursions are shorter, but the speed is less and they just compensate.  This is a handy feature for clocks. Why do you think the frequency increases?  As you get to very small excursions, you probably get more stick/slip, increasing the friction and decreasing the frequency.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of the physics of a ball, which bounces more as it stops. This doesn't apply to a pendulum though :)